# Javascript calculation giving wrong answer because of comma

Tags: javascript

I have a calculation which works fine until it hits a thousand separator, which is a comma. I have tried a few things trying to get rid of the comma but I can't seem to get it right. Below is the last thing I tried which was a total failure. The 'tot_amount' is the one I need the comma stripped from. I think I went down the wrong track and it should be doable without the extra 'tot' variable. Please assist.

```
    function updateDue() {

var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("tot_amount").value);
var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("eftposamount").value);
var tot = total.replace(",","");

// to make sure that they are numbers
if (!tot) { tot = 0; }
if (!val2) { val2 = 0; }

var ansD = document.getElementById("remainingval");
ansD.value = tot - val2;
}
```

Comment: Try using: `total.replace(",","","g")` instead

Comment: You are calling `parseInt` before attempting to replace the commas. You'll need to replace the commas first before attempting to parse to an integer.

Comment: @vihan I used some of this to fix my issue and it worked, so I took out the other var, and now have this line var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("tot_amount").value.replace(",", "")); ......what is the "g" for?

Comment: @Kilisi The `g` makes it replace **all** commas. It stands for "global"

Comment: @vihan—the [*replace* method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.replace) only accepts 2 arguments, not three. Your "g" flag is ignored.

Comment: @RobG hm. Works in my browser, no idea why. I can't find a spec for it though

Comment: @vihan—it's a [*Mozilla extension*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (apparently deprecated but not yet removed), not part of the spec. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Replacing

Your code is only removing one comma, try using this instead:

```
total.replace(/,/g, "");
```

The best way is to remove all non-number safe stuff and use that:

```
+total.replace(/[^\de.-]/gi, "")
```

> As you see I've a `g`
>
> The `g` stands for **global** meaning it will replace **all** commas instead of just the first one.

## String to Integers

Instead of:

```
var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("tot_amount").value);
var tot = total.replace(",","");
```

You must make it an integer after you parse it. A short way to parse a number is using `+`

```
var total = +document.getElementById("tot_amount").value.replace(/[^\de.-]/gi, "")
```

## Your code:

You can make your function this:

```
function updateDue() {
    document.getElementById("remainingval").value = 
        +document.getElementById("tot_amount").value.replace(/[^\de.-]/gi, "") -
        +document.getElementById("eftposamount").value.replace(/[^\de.-]/gi, "")
         || 0
}
```

The `||0` will remove the need for the ifs.

Comment: I'll accept this answer as correct as soon as it lets me, quick question, whats the "g' for

Comment: Your regex appears to have an unescaped `.` in the `[^\de.-]`. This will Match any character except a newline, which, when inverted, will not match as expected.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `parseInt` and `+` are semantically different, especially regarding exponents, decimals, and bases like octal.

Comment: @skeggse Yes but in very few cases that matters. The `.` is not unescaped because it is in a character class it will match the literal

Comment: @vihan oh, right. Sorry. I brought up the semantics because it becomes more important when processing unsanitized data.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `parseInt` on a comma-delimited string will give you unexpected results:

```
parseInt('1,000'); // => 1
```

Instead, you want to remove commas, and *then* parse the integer:

```
var i = +('1,000'.replace(/,/g, '')); // => 1000
```

The `//` part is simply `RegExp` notation, and the `g` afterwards is a flag that tells the parser to look for *global* instances of the expression. In your case, you want to remove *all* commas, so the `g` flag is appropriate.

For the sake of saving 7 characters in your code, you can simply coerce your value to an integer with `+` rather than calling `parseInt`.